# How can I inspect element in a UC Browser in Android Phone on my machine?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, uc-browser

When I use UC Browser for desktop my mobile view working fine.

But when I use UC Browser Mobile App and open my site .. It breaks and take more them for loading.

I just want to inspect remotely UC Browser Mobile app FORCSS/HTML javascript  Example we did in Chrome :

As we did in Chrome https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: One point i find that in UC browser if you do a client side APIs call then you have to add default headers in your client calling Lib. and framework..
Like in my angular JS I added "Content-type: application/json" in herders of APIs calling and i start getting response from servers as you know that angularJS's default "Content-type: application/json". buy I had to add that .... do that this also :)

Answer (score 2):

Recently we release uc-devtools，a standalone tools to debug the latest developer version of UC Browser.
Check this out:
https://plus.ucweb.com/docs/pwa/docs-zh/xy3whu?locale=en-US

https://plus.ucweb.com is the all in one international supporting site for developer.

Answer (score 0):

As of now you wont be able to connect and debug UC mobile browser on UC browser Desktop directly as like of chrome.

If you are working on any UI issue related UC browser in mobile. You can replicate it on IE emulator[Desktop].

**Setting required:**
Document Mode: IE10
width  320 or 360.
Orientation : portrait

It will replicate more or less same bugs like UC browser mobile.
[image]